# Signal R code doesn't work in live environment

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

The Signal R implementation what I have done works perfectly in localhost with two browsers on the same machine, but when I publish the code it faces some DNS resolution related problem and stops working when I test the published code on two different machines. I'm not sure what stops it from working.

Comment: Ensure that your signalr/hubs call is pointing to the correct location.  Keep in mind SignalR runs off of wherever you're hosting it so the path needs to be valid.

Comment: Resolved: The problem was with Application pool mode. Classic mode is not supported for SignalR. One needs to use integrated mode application pool only.

Found the solution from here:
[MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2013/03/21/hosting-a-signalr-application-on-windows-2008r2-and-iis-7-5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I should check is if you can access http://SomeDomain.com/signalr/hubs

That should load JS, if that doesn't work, you will need to start tracking things down from there. As "N. Taylor" states in the comments, your path to SignalR/HUBS might differ if you've changed things in development, so you will want to customize the above URL based on any customizations you've made in DEV.

Once you get the proper path to /signalr/hubs and get JS loading when you access that URL, it should be easier to get things tracked down a bit.